# Nodejs - Generating unique random alpha numeric random string for Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I have a use case where I need to generate alpha numeric capital case strings of length 25, so the total possible unique combinations are very high:

```
36 pow (25) = 808281277464764060643139600456536293376
```

The string is to be stored in `MySql` database table with `unique` set to `true`

I am using following code to generate the string:

```
const Chance = require('chance');
const chance = new Chance(Date.now() + Math.random());
let randomStr = chance.string({length: 25, 
                pool: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'});
console.log(randomStr);
```

Node.js can run in cluster mode, so value of timestamp can be same for different requests so I also added `Math.random()`. Is this enough to ensure that `MySql` unique constraint won't be violated by the random strings.

Comment: You want a universally-unique string that's largely alphanumeric? That sounds an awful lot like [a UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), which your database probably supports already.

Comment: @ssube uuid is 128 bit

Comment: Yes, UUIDs are 128 bits. That's significantly smaller than your 25-character identifier, while still being universally unique **and** optimized in most databases for fast lookups.

Comment: @ssube I haven't mentioned that I am going to use it for lookups and want to improve the lookup performance

Comment: Performance has little to do with it. The database is the only actor able to guarantee that a value is unique, so it should be the one producing those values. Most databases have fantastic UUID support, which happens to include performance optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this enough to ensure that MySQL unique constraint won't be violated by the random strings.

36<sup>25</sup> has 129 bit. If we apply the birthday problem, then you're likely getting a collision around 2<sup>64</sup> strings. You'll probably generate much less than that. This is only true provided that you use a good randomness source.

`Math.random()` is **not** a good randomness source.

Comment: Doesn't appending timestamp and math.random()  to generate seed guarantee a unique number atleast every nanosecond which should be enough if I am not using more than 4 node servers in a cluster

Comment: It's not guaranteed, but it's pretty unlikely. Also, you can even solve this without any randomness at all. Just give each node in the cluster a different identifier (a single character is enough). It's unlikely, but if two requests are handled at the same time in a single node server, then you can use a counter. Concatenate the node id, the counter and the timestamp in order to get a short and guaranteed unique ID.